# Seeking a free symbolic regression software

Tags: regression, machine-learning, genetic-algorithms

Now that Formulize / Eureqa started charging $2500 a year for using it and having crippled the trial version, does anyone know of any replacements that can do similar things like find an equation given data points?

It was free, but is now out of the price range of anyone that's not a company or school.

(it's a [symbolic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_regression) software)

Thanks

PS: I used to input an array into Formulize which would create periodic equations with 8000-44100 variables, then I would plug the equations back into octave and create several different periodic signals from the equations.

Comment: R has a symbolic regression package: http://rsymbolic.org/projects/rgp/wiki/Symbolic_Regression

Comment: For general symbolic computing, check out SymPy for a Python-based alternative to Mathematica, or Theano for another (allegedly very fast) Python solution. No personal experience with either.

Comment: FWIW, Nutonian still offers [free academic licenses of Eureqa](http://www.nutonian.com/products/eureqa/academic-license/).

Comment: @ssde The term "symbolic regression" is a misnomer; it has little to do with symbolic computing.  It refers to automatic curve fitting: the user specifies a set of functions and allowable ways of combining them (algebraic operations, usually) and the "symbolic regression" tries to find as close a (penalized) fit as possible among the class of such functions.

Comment: @whuber good to know. I assumed it was symbolic computing as per Aksakal's answer, but apparently that's mistaken too

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mathematica now, but before that [REDUCE](http://www.reduce-algebra.com/) was my tool. It's under FreeBSD license. It used to be better than anything in late '90s. I'm sure that commercial packages beat it in terms of bells and whistles, but when it comes to straight symbolic math, it probably holds its own.

I've heard good things about [SymPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SymPy), but have no personal experience with it.

Comment: You appear to have confounded "symbolic regresion" and "symbolic computation."  They have little in common.

Comment: Yes, jumped the gun on this one.